# Cassandra way to create and query nested list of objects

Tags: cassandra

I have a model of posts and their corresponding comments, like this:

```
{
    "id": "1234",
    "moment": "2021-02-19T10:00:00Z",
    "body": "Good morning!",
    "author": "Bob",
    "comments": [
        {
            "body": "Take care!",
            "moment": "2021-02-19T11:13:00Z",
            "author": "Bob"
        },
        {
            "body": "Hey there!",
            "moment": "2021-02-19T11:15:00Z",
            "author": "Maria"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using Cassandra 3.11.10, I managed to create and query a case insensitive LIKE search by text contained in post body:

```
CREATE TABLE post(
    id uuid, 
    moment timestamp, 
    body text, 
    author varchar,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
); 

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX body_idx ON post (body) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.NonTokenizingAnalyzer','case_sensitive': 'false'};

INSERT INTO post (id, moment, body, author) VALUES (uuid(), '2021-02-19T10:00:00Z', 'Good morning!', 'Bob');

SELECT * FROM post WHERE body LIKE '%morning%';
```

But how can I create a table structure for nested comments, and also search text in both post and comments bodies?

Comment: it's better to take Elasticsearch or Solr for this... Especially if it's scanning of all table - and SASI is a very experimental feature

Answer (score 1):

First, please, keep in mind that Cassandra's modeling is different from a relational database, and unfortunately, the [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is your friend on NoSQL, especially at Cassandra.
You need to focus on the data you want to retrieve from the database or a do [query-driven design](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/data_modeling/intro.html#query-driven-modeling).

However, if you cannot remodeling the system, there are a couple of solutions:

1. Append a Search Engine such as Sorl or ElasticSearch with Cassandra: This solution enables you to create a second service to do the whole search engine in this service.
   **Pro**: You can keep the Cassandra model similar to a relational.
   **Cons**: More operation complexity to maintain two services increases the difficulty of managing data from two different sources and synchronize them.
2. Use [Stratio](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index): that is a plugin where you add a Lucene index on Cassandra.

**Pro**: It has a full-text search engine integrated with Cassandra. You don't need to have a new infrastructure service and worry about the data replication in different services. It has support to UDT. Thus you can define the comments as UDT and search typically.
**Cons**: You need to include a jar in each Cassandra node. Besides, once Cassandra and Lucence are working on the same machine, it might impact performance, thus [look at the references](https://github.com/Stratio/cassandra-lucene-index/blob/branch-3.0.14/doc/documentation.rst).

3. Cassandra DSE: A commercial version that has several features, such as a search integration.
   **Pro**: A Search engine integrated with several features.
   **Cons**: There is not a free version.